# One object two foreign keys to the same table

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to have a post associated to two users. The author and the moderator. I am trying without success this code

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    post = db.relationship('Post', foreign_keys=['posts.id'], backref='post_user', lazy='dynamic')
    post_blame = db.relationship('Post', foreign_keys=['posts.moderated_by'], backref='post_blame', lazy='dynamic')    

class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    moderated_by = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
```

**Error:**

```
ArgumentError: Column-based expression object expected for argument 'foreign_keys'; got: 'posts.id', type <class 'str'>
```

Comment: Please post the full error traceback.

Comment: Solved based in this thread https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/2o4ejl/af_flask_sqlalchemy_two_foreign_keys_referencing/

Answer (score 18):

One of the issues here is that you are currently trying to use table columns in the relationship `foreign_keys`, rather than class attributes.

That is, instead of using `posts.id`, you should be using `Post.id`.  (In fact, to refer to a table column, you would need to use `posts.c.id`).

So, it is possible that your original code will work if you correct it to:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    post = db.relationship('Post', foreign_keys='Post.id', backref='post_user', lazy='dynamic')
    post_blame = db.relationship('Post', foreign_keys='Post.moderated_by', backref='post_blame', lazy='dynamic')
```

If it does not, then there several other options.  First, you could establish these relationships in the `Post` class, where it is less ambiguous for sqlalchemy to find the foreign key relationship.  Something like

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    moderated_by = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    post_user = db.relationship(User, foreign_keys=author_id, backref='post', lazy='dynamic')
    post_blame = db.relationship(User, foreign_keys=moderated_by, backref='post_blame', lazy='dynamic')
```

Note in this version, we don't need to pass the `foreign_keys` value as a string, we can just refer directly to the column in scope.

Alternatively, if you wish to establish these relationships within User, you may you need to give `sqlalchemy` more information, by using `primaryjoin` ... perhaps something like:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    post = db.relationship('Post', primaryjoin='User.id == Post.id', backref='post_user', lazy='dynamic')
    post_blame = db.relationship('Post', foreign_keys='User.id == Post.moderated_by', backref='post_blame', lazy='dynamic')
```

Comment: first example, same type of error that i am getting ( Column-based expression object expected for argument 'foreign_keys'). second example relationship() got an unexpected keyword argument 'primary_join'

Comment: @anvd primary_join should have been primary join.  Have also just noticed that you were using table names, not class names in your `foreign_keys` and I've revised my answer accordingly.  Let me know how it goes!

Comment: I don't really care about your bounty, I also don't particularly care about trying to completely replicate your table and database structure to help you in a reasonably simply problem.  I am merely trying to provide pointers ... you know, I suspect you might be **capable of doing things like looking up documentation**.  For example, a simple look at the relationship api would have told you that `primary_join` was meant to be `primaryjoin` ...

Comment: Apparently the problem is not so simple. 65 views after four days and I only have "guesses". btw thanks anyway

Comment: @donkopotamus, this helped me, so thanks! On a side note, the docs for sqlalchemy could do with some improvements. For this instance, this is what [it says](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.foreign_keys): `a list of columns which are to be used as ...... be passed as a Python-evaluable string when using Declarative.` Can be confusing sometimes. I had to google to get here, for an example!

Comment: @donkopotamus I came across this question from search, and was intrigued by your assertion to use Post.id instead of posts.id (and that posts.c.id is more correct). All my code is using the latter method, and I'm basing it on the examples in http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html . Can't find any official docs stating that class names are preferred to table names, could you give a pointer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41632573/sqlalchemy-how-to-define-a-foreign-key-column-using-model-class-instead-of-phy also seems to agree that we should use class names (and then add that it can't be done in strings, but in my own experience using table names in strings works!)