# SqlAlchemy - How to define a foreign key column using model class instead of physical table name

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

### In brief

I want to use model class to define a foreign-key column.

My [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=SqlAlchemy%20-%20How%20to%20define%20a%20foreign%20key%20column%20using%20model%20class%20instead%20of%20physical%20table%20name) on this topic is not helpful so I asked here.

### In full

Normally we define column which is a foreign key via physical table name e.g. guided [here](http://www.ergo.io/blog/sqlalchemy-relationships-from-beginner-to-advanced/)

```
author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('author.id'))
```

The phrase `ForeignKey('author.id')` helps define column author_id as foreign key column - it refers to talble `author` where `author` is the table name.

I want to use model class name i.e.

```
author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Author.id))
```

But this code gets error

> Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship XX.YYY - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.

How can we get to it?

Comment: Can you please post the traceback of the error?

Comment: @matino I updated the error trace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### In brief

- From model other than Author

  `author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Author.__table__.c.id))`
- From Author model itself i.e. self-referential - just list the column name

  `author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(id))`
- CANNOT use string value

  `author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Author.id'))`

### Full details

[ForeignKey](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKey) accepts column as first argument which can be of type `Column` or string in format `schema_name.table_name.column_name` or `table_name.column_name`. Columns that you define in declarative model turn to `InstumentedAttribute` objects. That is why `db.ForeignKey(Author.id)` leads to an error. You can access actual column via `__table__` attribute of a model:

```
author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Author.__table__.c['id']))
```

or

```
author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Author.__table__.c.id))
```

If you need to define self-referencing foreign key you can simply pass the name of column. While declaration of a model is not finished yet it still has `Column` type:

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(id))
```

Note that you CANNOT define foreign key this way:

```
author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Author.id'))
```

You need to specify *physical table* name, *mapping class* name won't work for it.

Comment: How can we pass self-referential for `db.ForeignKey(...)` i.e. the column is currently inside Author class too?

Comment: @NamGVU Updated my answer: while declaration of a model is not finished `id` column is still of `Column` type. It turns to `InstrumentedAttribute` after declaration is complete.

Comment: Got that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One more thing @SergeyShubin, because we have to use model class name `Author` in **string** value i.e. cannot use the class name directly (due to circular reference in Python), calling `Author.__table__` is not available. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You solution is working in case we can import the model class!

Comment: @NamGVU If you want to use `ForeignKey(Author.id)`: there is no way you can use a class without importing it. If you want to use `ForeignKey('Author.id')`: it is _possible_ but SQLAlchemy has no such feature (you can try to subclass `ForeignKey` and add this feature but it could be rather challenging).

Comment: I see, please update your answer to clarify that and we get it accepted. Thank you!

Comment: @NamGVU Added the summary from our comments. Not mentioned about attempt to use a class from other module without importing it - it is beyond the scope of the question. Thanks!

Comment: Great thanks. We made a great article on this. Hope sqlalchemy to be upgraded to support db.ForeignKey('Class.column') soon.